Integral involving composition of cosine and log
I am trying to prove that

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x}\log{(1-x^2)}\cos{(p \log{x})}dx = \frac{1}{p^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2p}\coth\left(\frac{p\pi}{2}\right),\quad p \in \mathbb{R}$$

where $\coth {x} =  \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$. At $p=0$, we take the limiting value. It is taken from "Table of Integrals, series, and products" 7th edition by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. Where they state that on page 595, $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x}\log{(1-x^2)}\cos{(p \log{x})}dx = \frac{1}{2p^{2}}+\frac{\pi}{2p}\coth\left(\frac{p\pi}{2}\right)$ which seemed incorrect to me as the right side is mostly positive. I don't have a complete proof, but I think the correct approach would be integration by parts, $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x}\log{(1-x^2)}\cos{(p \log{x})}dx = \left. \ln(1-x^2)\frac{\sin(p\ln(x))}{x}\right|_0^1-\frac{1}{P}\int_0^{1}\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}\sin{(p\ln{x})}dx\\ = \frac{2}{P}\int_0^{1} \frac{x}{1-x^2}\sin{(p\ln{x})} \overset{x=e^{-t}}{=} -\frac{2}{p}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{pt}}{e^{2t}-1}dt.$$
where I am currently stuck at the last integral. Feynman's trick is not gonna work as the integral is gonna be unbounded.  How should I proceed from here?
Edit: Maybe the approach is related to this solution which uses contour integration.

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x}\log{(1-x^2)}\cos{(p \log{x})}dx &=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(1-e^{-2w})\cos(pw)dw \quad \left(w\mapsto -\ln(x)\right)\\
&=& \Re \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(1-e^{-2w})e^{ipw}dw  \\
&=& -\Re \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2wn}e^{ipw}dw\\
&=& -\Re \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-w(2n-ip)}dw  \\
&=& -\Re \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n-ip)} \\
&=& -2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2+p^2}\\
&=&  \frac{1}{p^2} -\frac{\pi\coth\left(\frac{p\pi}{2}\right)}{2p}
\end{eqnarray*}
The last series is the partial fractions decomposition of the hyperbolic cotangent.

Thank you, this was clear and crisp. @Bertrand87

$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\log(1-x^2)\cos(p\log x)dx = \operatorname{Re}\left\{\int_0^1x^{ip-1}\log(1-x^2)dx\right\}$$
and
$$\int_0^1x^{ip-1}\log(1-x^2)dx = \frac{x^{ip}-1}{ip}\log(1-x^2)\Biggr|_0^1+\frac{2}{ip}\int_0^1\frac{x^{ip+1}-x}{1-x^2}dx$$
$$= \frac{i}{p}\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{\frac{ip}{2}}}{1-x}dx$$
by choosing the antiderivative of the monomial which is $0$ at $x=1$. Can you complete the computation from here using Taylor series or any method of your choice?

Observing that
$$
 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left(1-x^2\right) \cos (p \ln x) d x = \Re\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left(1-x^2\right) e^{i p \ln x} d x 
= \Re \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left(1-x^2\right) x^{p i} d x
$$
Putting $y=x^2$ and expanding $\ln(1-y)$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left(1-x^2\right) \cos (p \ln x) d x 
& =-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \Re \int_0^1 y^{n+\frac{p i}{2}-1} d y \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \Re\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{pi}{2}} \cdot \frac{n-\frac{p i}{2}}{n-\frac{pi}{2}}\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+\frac{p^2}{4}}\right)\\&=-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 n^2+p^2}\\&= \frac{1}{p^2} -\frac{\pi\coth\left(\frac{p\pi}{2}\right)}{2p}
\end{aligned}
$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over x}
\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}
\cos\pars{p\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x\right\vert_{\, p\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}}
\\[5mm] = & \ \Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}} \over x}
\expo{\ic\,\verts{p}\ln{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sr{x\ \mapsto\ x^{1/2}}{=}
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}x^{\ic\verts{p}/2\ -\ 1}\,\,
\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\lim_{\pars{\epsilon,\nu}\ \to\
\pars{0^{+}\ ,\ 0}}\,\,
\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\epsilon\ -\ 1\ +\ \verts{p}\ic/2}\,\,\,
\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{\nu} - 1}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\lim_{\pars{\epsilon,\nu}\ \to\
\pars{0^{+}\ ,\ 0}}\,\,\,\partiald{}{\nu}\left[\Gamma\pars{\epsilon + \verts{p}\ic/2}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\epsilon + \verts{p}\ic/2 + \nu + 1}\right.
\\ &  \left.\phantom{AAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
-\, {1 \over \epsilon + \verts{p}\ic/2}\right]
\\[5mm] = & \
-\,{1 \over \verts{p}}\,\Im\Psi\pars{1 + {\verts{p} \over 2}\ic}
\\[5mm] & \sr{\color{red}{\LARGE\S}}{=}
-\,{1 \over \verts{p}}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2\pars{\verts{p}/2}} +
{\pi \over 2}\coth\pars{\pi{\verts{p} \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over p^{2}} - {\pi \over 2p}\coth\pars{\pi p \over 2}}}\qquad
\left\vert\rule{0pt}{1cm}\quad\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function\right. \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\color{red}{\Large\S}:}$
See ${\bf{\mbox{6.3.13}}}$ in A & S
